# Variables with the same name when using for loop in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, scope

Consider the following code snippet:

```
unsigned int i;
double* u = new double [10];

for (i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    double u = 5.0;
    // Other code
}

delete[] u;
```

Is it okay to use the variable name u twice? Or is this frowned upon? Will the code fail to compile using certain compilers?

EDIT: Is this better? Or is it still confusing for future maintainers of the code?

```
unsigned int i;
double* u = new double [10];
// Do stuff with u
delete[] u;

for (i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    double u = 5.0;
    // Other code
}
```

Comment: Surely you need to use the outer `u` inside the loop? Otherwise, what's the point?

Comment: The inner variable **u** hides the outer variable **u** in their scope and inners scopes, depending the case would be possible or not to refer the outer variable in some way.

Comment: If I remembered correctly it will work, but it's a bad practice and you almost never have to do this.

Comment: This is just a simple example. The outer `u` is not used inside the loop but it is used after the loop.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why not?  The scope of the `u` in the loop is from the definition until the bottom of the loop.  Outside of that scope, the outer `u` is visible.

Comment: @JamesKanze I misread, deleted that comment.

Comment: It is not okay to use the same variable name twice, if you can avoid it dont even use the same variable name in your whole program XD.

Comment: @Simon Nonsense.  `i` is the most natural name for an index variable, and so is what you should use.  (Obviously, any variable named `i` should be local.)

Comment: @JamesKanze except for indexes / counters ofc

Comment: @Simon Except for local variables, members, etc.  While you typically don't want one variable masking another in a function, there's no problem with using the same variable name for two different variables elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

The code

```
double u = 5.0;
```

inside of the loop will shadow the definition

```
double* u = new double [10];
```

made prior to it.
All of your code inside the loop just sees `double u`. It's meant to compile fine, and besides introducing confusion for future maintainers of the code, there's nothing wrong from a syntactical point of view.

---

**Note:**
If you aren't using `double* u` inside of the loop, there's no point defining this variable before it. As a rule of thumb:

> Local variable definitions should appear nearest before their first point of usage.

---

**As for your edited question:**
Yes this will be clearer, in the sense that one could see the intend `double* u;` shouldn't be used after the `delete[] u;`. Though it's neither safe, and still confusing, if one's not spotting the shadowing definition of `double u;` inside of the loop immediately.

The IMHO overall better solution, to not confuse anyone, would be to factor out the code in the loop, or the code dealing with the `double* u` into a separate function, or even simply use a different variable name.

Comment: Say the outer `u` is only used before the loop. Is it still confusing for future maintainers of the code if I move `delete[] u;` before the loop. [**I EDITED THE QUESTION TO REFLECT THIS**]

Comment: @krylov _'Is it still confusing for future maintainers ...'_ I'd say no. But IMHO it would be better to completely factor out the code dealing with the array to a separate function, or simply use different names.

Comment: Would the downvoters mind to explain what should be improved in this answer, or where I state something wrong please?

Comment: @krylov You don't need to shout about your edits to me BTW. I'm old, but neither blind or deaf so far :P ...

Answer (score 1):

That will work with most compilers. However, it is generally not a good practice as it can lead to confusion on the part of the programmer, particularly if the program becomes large.

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of long debugging sessions supporting that.